# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value' while copying column from one workingsheet to another

Tags: python, excel, tuples, openpyxl, attributeerror

I am trying yo copy one column from sheet 1 to sheet 0
My program is reaching to the cells where the values need to be copied but I am not able to copy the actual values in those cells.

I am keep getting attributeError.

Below is the code I have developed.

can someone help me to figure this out?

```
def updateSignOff(self):
        ConfigDetails.logger.info("process Signoff Start ")  
        try:
            workbook = load_workbook(filename=self.outputFile)
            workbook.active = 1    
            sheet = workbook.active
#findng month and getting values from sheet 1              
            Month = sheet ['F1']
            print(Month.value)


            for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=5,max_row=13,min_col=13,max_col=13,values_only=True):
                BillingValue=value
                print(BillingValue)
                print(len(BillingValue))            

            workbook.active = 0 
            sheet = workbook.active
#           
#finding Column in signoffsheet (sheet 0 ) from using Month Variable             


            for col in sheet.iter_cols():
                for cell in col:
                    if cell.value == Month.value:
                        columnvalue = cell.column
                        print(columnvalue)
                        for cell in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=7,max_row=14,min_col=columnvalue,max_col=columnvalue):
                            cell.value = float(BillingValue.value)
                            print(cell.value)


#            summryRow = 'J'+str(self.summaryRow)
#           sheet[summryRow]=0
            workbook.save(filename=self.outputFile)
            ConfigDetails.logger.info(" Process Signoff completed")
```

I am getting error at:

```
cell.value = float(BillingValue.value)
```

Comment: You've made BillingValue a string, then you try to call `.value` on it, but as the error states, strings don't have `.value` attributes. Did you mean `str(BillingValue.value)`? Or just `str(BillingValue)`?

Comment: @G.Anderson I tried str(BillingValue.value) as well but it gave me same error as 'tuple' object has no attribute value. I basically needs to assign Billingvalues to those cells. I do not know how to fix this

Comment: @G.Anderson I mean str(BillingValue.value) as I want to assign those values to the column

Comment: It sounds like there's an issue with `BillingValue`. Have you printed it or debugged it to see if that variable actually is what you think it is?

Comment: @G.Anderson BillingValue is comming up as tuple.  So I need to format that to assign it to cells

Comment: That's not much info, but it's clear that using `.value` is, in any case, the wrong avenue to attempt. Are you trying to write the whole tuple to the cell? `...=str(BillingValue)` Just one of the tuple elements? `...=str(BillingValue[0])`. What is your expectation of calling `.value` on a tuple?

Comment: @G.Anderson I have 8 values in that tuple which I need to assign to the cells in that column. I think you are right there is no point using `.Value` with the tuple. But at the same time I do not know any other alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211753/discussion-between-sachin-and-g-anderson).